# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors - Android Studio

Tags: android, mobile

When I rebuild my project in Android Studio, I get this error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
 Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs

I tried multiple solutions but the error is still there. Any idea what the problem might be?

This is from my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.HamzaAnsari.ShimmyBall"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11" android:targetSdkVersion="23"></uses-sdk>

<application 
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
android:label="ShimmyBall"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:allowBackup="true">

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />

    <activity android:name=".PTPlayer"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:configChanges="orientation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

These were the merging errors I found:
 `Merging Errors: Warning Element meta-data#com.google.android.gms.version at AndroidManifest.xml:32:1-113 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:15:9-16:69 app main manifest (this file), line 31 Error: uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 11 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library /Users/ansariha92/Documents/Game Projects/Buildbox Projects/ShimmyBallAndroid12/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.google.android.gms/play-services-ads-lite/11.0.4/AndroidManifest.xml Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.ads" to force usage`

Comment: "I can't find the specific errors that it's referring to" -- please edit your question and provide the specific errors, by copying and pasting the information from Android Studio.

Comment: Please show us error logs